# Simplify polygons of sf object

Tags: r, simplify, sf

How do I simplify an `sf` polygon without introducing gaps and slivers?

With a shapefile, for example, I would use `rmapshaper::ms_simplify()`:

```
library("pryr")
library("rgdal")
library("rmapshaper")

download.file("https://borders.ukdataservice.ac.uk/ukborders/easy_download/prebuilt/shape/England_gor_2011.zip",
              destfile = "regions.zip")
unzip("regions.zip")
regions <- readOGR(".", "england_gor_2011")
object_size(regions)
# ~13MB

regions <- ms_simplify(regions)
object_size(regions)
# < 1MB
```

I've tried `sf::st_cast()` which, from the man pages, states:

> Cast geometry to another type: either simplify, or cast explicitly

and:

> to argument: character; target type, if missing, simplification is tried; when x is of type sfg (i.e., a single geometry) then to needs to be specified.

When I've left `to` as missing this hasn't worked as expected though (I knew it was too good to be true!):

```
library("sf")
regions <- sf::read_sf("england_gor_2011.shp")
object_size(regions)
# ~13MB

regions <- sf::st_cast(regions)
object_size(regions)
# Still 13MB
```

Currently I'm opening the file with `rgdal::readOGR()`, simplifying it, saving this, then loading this again with `sf`.

Is there a better way?

---

### `rgeos::gSimplify()`

@s.k 's suggestion of `rgeos::gSimplify()` can do topologically-aware simplifications (i.e. simplifies without creating slivers) when specified with the following arguments:

```
library("rgeos")
regions_gSimplify <- gSimplify(regions, tol = 0.05, topologyPreserve = TRUE)
```

`gSimplify` doesn't preserve the `@data` frame, though, so we should re-create it:

```
regions_df <- regions@data
regions_gSimplify <- sp::SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(regions_gSimplify, regions_df)
```

And this does indeed result in a smaller file size (can tweak `tol` argument to get it smaller) and I confirmed this hadn't created any slivers by examining it in QGIS.

```
object_size(regions_gSimplify)
# ~8MB
```

So although this is a valid alternative to `rmapshaper::ms_simplify()` I still have the same problem, namely that it doesn't work with `sf`:

```
regions_sf <- sf::read_sf("england_gor_2011.shp")
object_size(regions_sf)

regions_gSimplify <- gSimplify(regions_sf, topologyPreserve = TRUE, tol = 0.05)
# Error in gSimplify(regions_sf, topologyPreserve = TRUE, tol = 0.05) : 
# no slot of name "proj4string" for this object of class "sf"
```

[@obrl_soil 's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/243576/24270) can also be applied to `gSimplify()`, just use it in place of `ms_simplify()`.

Comment: Do you have any access to a Douglas–Peucker algorithm? It is widely know for features simplification in GIS world. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217413/why-is-rs-implementation-of-the-douglas-peucker-algorithm-so-slow & https://www.r-bloggers.com/simplifying-spatial-polygons-in-r/

Comment: Isn't `st_simplify` supposed to do that? (didn't use it, yet)

Comment: @LoBu Yep, that's it! I can't believe I missed that! Care to answer and I'll accept it, as that's probably the canonical `sf` answer. Thanks.

Comment: @s.k See my edited question and thanks for the suggestion

Comment: ooh, I hadn't noticed `st_simplify`, thanks for pointing it out. I do prefer the algorithm that `rmapshaper::ms_simplify` defaults to over all the others I've tried so far, but I'll have a play with the new option (update: whoa proceed with caution, `preserveTopology = TRUE` definitely doesn't work properly yet)

Comment: Good to know. What about opening a bug report on this ?

Comment: @obrl_soil `preserveTopology = TRUE` seemed to work for `tol` up to about 1000 (of course YMMV), after that things got a bit psychedelic

Comment: @LoBu I'm honestly not sure if its a true bug or a semantic thing, 'preserve topology' seems to mean different things to different people in this space. It does deserve disussion, though.

Comment: @obrl_soil It works for tolerances up to about 1000 on the polygons I've used in the question (`regions`) but beyond that it no longer preserves topology. As it breaks at a certain point I'd say that's not intended behaviour

Comment: Yeah, I managed to break it at 25m on a more local-scale dataset. Issue opened here - https://github.com/edzer/sfr/issues/381

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can cast an sf object to sp, for packages that don't yet support sf - I do this a fair bit for raster/polygon interactions. So you could do:

```
simplepolys <- rmapshaper::ms_simplify(input = as(sfobj, 'Spatial')) %>%
  st_as_sf()
```

Comment: This technique - casting as a spatial object, simplifying, then re-casting as an `sf` object - worked perfectly, and can be used with `rmapshaper::ms_simplify()` or `rgeos::gSimplify()`. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Cool cool, just be aware that the topology of interlocking polygons is only truly preserved with rmapshaper's approach. If your input data is all isolated, non-interlocking polygons, you can safely use any of the available simplification algs.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer because the more canonical `sf::st_simplify()` isn't robust at high tolerances at the time of writing, although obviously this may change.

Comment: I am currently working on support for `sf` objects in **rmapshaper**. `ms_simplify` is available for `sf` objects in the development version. I'd love early testers - if you want to try it out, you can install with `devtools::install_github("ateucher/rmapshaper", ref = "sf")`

Comment: As of `rmapshaper` version 0.3.0, the call to `as( , "Spatial")` is no longer required.